# Type problems in reducer , typescript with useReducer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, types, react-hooks

I am having a type problem with TypeScript where when working with the React hook `useReducer` the console throws the following error:

> Function lacks ending return statement and return type does not include 'undefined'. TS2366
>
> 5 | const Reducer = (state: InitialStateType, action: Action): InitialStateType => {

I have tried to assign type to the value returned by the submit handle before doing the actions. It is not that the problem seems to be linked to my services or my reducer. I really wish that you could guide me...

reducerSensor.ts

```
import { InitialStateType } from "../interfaces/interfaces"
import { Action } from "../types/types";

const Reducer = (state: InitialStateType, action: Action) : InitialStateType => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'REQUEST_GET': {
            return {
                ...state,
                loading: true,
            };
        }
        case 'SUCCESS_GET': {
            return {
                ...state,
                loading: false,
                sensors: state.sensors.concat(action.payload)
            };
        }
        case 'ERROR_GET': {
            return {
                ...state,
                loading: false,
                error: action.error,
            };
        } 
        case 'REQUEST_CREATE' : {
            return {
                ...state,
                loading: true,
            };
        }
        case 'SUCCESS_CREATE' : {
            return {
                ...state,
                loading: false,
                sensors: [...state.sensors, action.payload]
            };
        }
        case 'ERROR_CREATE': {
            return {
                ...state,
                loading: false,
                error: action.error,
            };
        }
        default:
            throw new Error('Error in the change of state');
    }
};

export default Reducer;
```

ListSensor.ts

```
import { FC ,useEffect , useReducer} from 'react'
import '../../styles/ListSensors.css'
import FormSensors from '../FormSensors/FormSensors'
import * as sensorServices from '../../services/sensorServices'
import Reducer from '../../Reducers/reducerSensor'
import { InitialStateType, Sensor } from '../../interfaces/interfaces'

const ListSensors: FC<HTMLDataListElement>= () => {

const initState: InitialStateType = {
    sensors: [],
    loading: true,
    error: false
}

const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(Reducer, initState )

const { sensors, loading, error } = state;

useEffect(() => {
    dispatch({ type: 'REQUEST_GET' });
    const loadSensors = async () => {
        const res = await sensorServices.getSensors();
        if (res.status === 200) {
            dispatch({ type: 'SUCCESS_GET', payload: res.data });
            return;
        }
        dispatch({ type: 'ERROR_GET', error: res.data});
    };
    loadSensors();
}, []);

const handleCreate = (objectSensor : Sensor)  => {
    dispatch({ type: 'REQUEST_CREATE' });
        const createSensor = async () => {
            const res = await sensorServices.createNewSensor(objectSensor);
            if (res.status === 200) {
                dispatch({ type: 'SUCCESS_CREATE', payload: res.data });
                return;
            }
    dispatch({ type: 'ERROR_CREATE', error: res.data});
        };
   createSensor();
}

    return (
        <div>
             {loading ? (
                <p>loading...</p>
            ) : error ? (
                <p>{error}</p>
            ) : (
            <div className='datatable-container'>
                <table className="datatable">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Status</th>
                            <th>Name</th>
                            <th>Ubication (lat / lng)</th>
                            <th>MinVal</th>
                            <th>MaxVal</th>
                            <th>Events</th>
                            <th>Options</th>         
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <FormSensors  event={handleCreate}/>     
                        {
                            sensors && sensors.length > 0 ? sensors.map((sensor: Sensor) => (
                                <tr key={sensor._id}>
                                    <td><span className={sensor.active ? "active" : "inactive"}></span></td>
                                    <td>{sensor.name}</td>
                                    <td>{sensor.ubication[0]}° lat , {sensor.ubication[1]}° lng</td>
                                    <td>{sensor.minVal}°</td>
                                    <td>{sensor.maxVal}°</td>
                                    <td><button  className="button button-event"><i className="material-icons">sensors</i></button></td>
                                    <td> <button className="button button-delete"><i className="material-icons">delete</i></button> <button className="button button-update"><i className="material-icons">edit</i></button></td>   
                                </tr>
                            )
                          )  : null
                        }
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
            )}
    </div>
    )
}

export default ListSensors
```

SensorServices.ts

```
import axios from "axios";
import { Sensor } from "../interfaces/interfaces";

const API = "http://localhost:3001";

export const getSensors = async () => {
  return await axios.get(`${API}/sensors`);
};

export const createNewSensor = async (sensor: Sensor) => {
    return await axios.post(`${API}/sensor`, sensor);
  };
  
  export const deleteSensorById = async (id: string) => {
    return await axios.delete(`${API}/sensors/${id}`);
  };
  
  export const updateSensor = async (id: string, sensor: Sensor) => {
    return await axios.put(`${API}/sensors/${id}`, sensor);
  };
```

types.ts

```
import { ChangeEvent } from 'react';
import { Sensor } from '../interfaces/interfaces';

export type Action =
    { type: 'REQUEST_GET'}
|   { type: 'SUCCESS_GET', payload: Sensor }
|   { type: 'ERROR_GET' , error: string }
|   { type: 'ERROR_CREATE' , error: string }
|   { type: 'REQUEST_CREATE' }
|   { type: 'SUCCESS_CREATE', payload: Sensor }

export type InputChange = ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement | HTMLTextAreaElement>;

export type SelectChange = ChangeEvent<HTMLSelectElement >
```

interfaces.ts

```
export interface Sensor {
    _id?: string;
    name: string;
    ubication: number[]
    maxVal: number;
    minVal: number;
    active: boolean;
    createdAt?: string | Date;
    updatedAt?: string | Date;
  }

  export interface  SensorForm {
    name: string;
    lat: string;
    lng: string;
    active: boolean;
  }
  export interface InitialStateType  {
    sensors: Sensor[],
    loading: Boolean,
    error: Boolean | String 
  }
```

Comment: try to share minimum reproducible example in ts playground. It will be easier to answer

Answer (score 1):

In:

```
const Reducer = (state: InitialStateType, action: Action) : InitialStateType => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'REQUEST_GET': {
            return { ...state, loading: true, };
        }
        case 'SUCCESS_GET': {
            return {
                ...state,
                loading: false,
                sensors: state.sensors.concat(action.payload)
            };
        }
        case 'ERROR_GET': {
            return {...state, loading: false, error: action.error, };
        } 
        case 'REQUEST_CREATE' : {
            return { ...state, loading: true, };
        }
        case 'SUCCESS_CREATE' : {
            return { ...state, loading: false, sensors: [...state.sensors, action.payload] };
        }
        case 'ERROR_CREATE': {
            return {
                ...state,
                loading: false,
                error: action.error,
            };
        }
        // ADD A DEFAULT CLAUSE HERE <---------------
    }
};
```

Your `switch` should have a `default` clause. Otherwise TypeScript infers it may return `undefined`, because that's what will happen if `action.type` is not matched by any `case`.

If you don't have a `default` value for that scenario, you can simply `throw new Error()`:

```
        case 'ERROR_CREATE': {
            return {
                ...state,
                loading: false,
                error: action.error,
            };
        }
        default:
            throw new Error('some meaningful message (optional)');
    }
};
```

EDIT:

Types work fine this way. See [typescript playground demo](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcCCBjGBLCA7OAXgFgAoOCuAbwWWAC44ByAJQFEBFAVTYGUAVAPoBxNvyYBfMgB9KNJCkZNeXAMKq+vEWKYAaOGACGiADYRDAE0a9geAM7Q4U0rIry6StixYB5FtvE4fWAoKGhGOxgobDwAcycZOVpFZi9ff1V2NH42JiC4ELCoCKiY+OdXamSGZnZuPiFMtmzchJckhRrlNQ1eLSaWvQNjM0trWwcoNrJQSFg4GJgQgDNDDFQbe0cqMko4QWwLAH4S6LiAbl3KPEMAWxrIs9jL8koAVwAjbAxDHHxGPBvW4fEIAbQAulcKLdDCAAGqGEwAoEgqAvPa3GIIpFwQHAkLoyhrHAANxqHwgEBMwEMeEJFAwUBpSwsaBgJzgjzKcFkABFfsB6XA3mALALWezTty+QLCc4rrNoPBFis1qg4JtJgAxaC3ahQ3F3B6lC4Gky-KWm14UExxS3PA3E7BkxgUqk0ulXZwURXzFVQVbrOAASTw2BwiN4MAF-DobgNdgm0Ds4y2UAhujN5gsZUYACFKdTaZnrQVQuE4AX3bSeRqTfEvWQyBh8JE4CxgBY3uspoQ4AAKSICxih8PYSPRpaxlD6J3-dBYXB4ACUcBHYYjJijMbjhAAfPrS3YAO7hjAACwHc7wADpOqudqW9j9E7VODwBAEmIxH3s-5QmRgN4oAIX9-3AigbygoclhLCCINGHM7QQKA3mAOD4IoCQhT2b1wJfVBunUTQvx-A0IMA4DQPIzC4Cgm8YPQmjMMQ3M4FWExEww2jKETNMU05SdgAYpMoDsG8WzwH4YH7a8byMUxs2XZi-2wlS8P-AjUm8PxSMPHjKJA-SeMoejGO4kzWOQjiuJUiDCgrOSHKgCyILUp9KAkOAVK01h3waQQBhyPIyI8-9DOosL4LMoTXNoqzYkYKI0Li-93LcnzDFfIjen6LJgrXYzMIioqTJigVUvghLGBspioogvjJgE0FyqWET+NnRd8HkkZs0herPJwzzMuytJdKC3JQoM4AgKMsCTLo6DYrs8DqvYxFbIG-9nMYJzyxclasKGrCVIsYBVjeEwYHoQ6EHPMJj1xYBHrYfb+yYV6igWAgYHPVAL1pWJUAgZZBIFJhlyFZx3JmcAlTgM6Lqu9tO27AkgA).

Comment: dont work :( , the same error

Comment: What did you do, exactly? Can you post the updated code for the `Reducer`?

Comment: yeah !!! look is updated

Comment: Try restarting your tsc or IDE. Something must be cached/not compiled, because the typings work, check the link at the bottom of the answer I just edited

Answer (score 0):

As a best practice, try to add `default` case which returns the untouched state (doesn't necessarily need to throw an error).

```
import { InitialStateType } from "../interfaces/interfaces"
import { Action } from "../types/types";

const Reducer = (state: InitialStateType, action: Action) : InitialStateType => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'REQUEST_GET': {
            return {
                ...state,
                loading: true,
            };
        }
        case 'SUCCESS_GET': {
            return {
                ...state,
                loading: false,
                sensors: state.sensors.concat(action.payload)
            };
        }
        case 'ERROR_GET': {
            return {
                ...state,
                loading: false,
                error: action.error,
            };
        } 
        case 'REQUEST_CREATE' : {
            return {
                ...state,
                loading: true,
            };
        }
        case 'SUCCESS_CREATE' : {
            return {
                ...state,
                loading: false,
                sensors: [...state.sensors, action.payload]
            };
        }
        case 'ERROR_CREATE': {
            return {
                ...state,
                loading: false,
                error: action.error,
            };
        }
        default:
            return state;
    }
};

export default Reducer;
```